# How to replay messages for late consumer

Tags: activemq-classic, message-queue

I am trying to figure out how to accommodate the following use case:

I have a producer which publishes messages. I have a pool of consumers, each of which need a complete copy of all the messages produced. I do not know ahead of time which consumers will need a copy of the message or when they will connect to the broker (it could be before messages are published, during production, or after production has finished).

I have tried solving this with ActiveMQ and ActiveMQ apollo but I have not been able to find a solution. I am open to trying any technology.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [retroactive consumer](http://activemq.apache.org/retroactive-consumer.html) functionality in ActiveMQ 5.x.

A retroactive consumer is just a regular JMS Topic consumer who indicates that at the start of a subscription every attempt should be used to go back in time and send any old messages (or the last message sent on that topic) that the consumer may have missed.

You mark a consumer as being retroactive as follows:

```
topic = new ActiveMQTopic("TEST.Topic?consumer.retroactive=true");
consumer = session.createConsumer(topic);
```

Comment: @justin-bertramthanks, Looking at the link you posted I am not sure how Subscription Recovery Policy configuration would take place. Does this happen in the broker config file or is it something the consumer can set on a case by case basis?

Comment: I was able to add a section to my broker's config file after having a look at an example I found here: https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/assembly/src/release/examples/conf/activemq-demo.xml .  I am wondering if I can change the policy at the consumer level.

Comment: In what way were you wanting to change the policy?

Comment: I was thinking that some clients may be interested in recovering different sets of data. For example 5 min vs 24 hrs. As far as I can tell this is a server level config. I also noticed the policy does not work with virtual destinations.

Comment: I don't believe that clients can specify how far back they would like to go.

Comment: In a network of brokers situation, would be able to specify a Subscription Recovery Policy on a broker by broker basis?

Comment: I don't know the answer to that question. I'd recommend you post a new question about this particular issue or modify your existing question as your use-case seems a fair bit more complex than described in your original question (which seems to be a perfect fit for retroactive consumers).

Comment: I updated the comment to address the review. While I understand the point made in the review, I think the opposite argument could be made - i.e. information taken from the linked page could become invalid if the linked page changes.